# If Statement only matches on first pass through loop

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

Ok, I'm a teacher and I have made a google form which asks for a period, assignment, and a due date.  After that, I can select students to send an email home to parents (It's for late assignments, the kids will hate it I'm sure).

I'm having a problem with the script only matching the first match in an "if" statement.  Here is what's going on:
[image: Form responses]

The image above shows the responses. An email template uses the period, assignment and due date cells to make an email. (That works)  The script uses the emails in the "Students" cell.

[image: roster list]

Next, the script uses the sheet above to create an array of values.  A loop begins with the first email address from the "students" cell in the form response sheet (the first one). A nested loop then iterates through the student emails in the roster sheet and tries to match the emails.  When a match is found, the parent emails are gathered and used to send the email.

Here is my code!

```
    function homeworkEmail() {
  var lastRow = sheet1.getLastRow();
  var emailArray = "";

  for (c=4; c<=9; c+=1) { //begin array starting with P1 column and end with P6 column 
    var students = sheet1.getRange(lastRow,c).getValue();
    if (students) {
      var sendToStudents = students.split(',');
    }

  }
  var period = sheet1.getRange(lastRow,3).getValue(); //Value of period column (3)
  var assignment = sheet1.getRange(lastRow,10).getValue(); //Value of assignment column (10)
  var due = sheet1.getRange(lastRow,11).getValue(); //Value of due date column (11)
  var allRosterValues = sheet2.getDataRange().getValues();


  for (s=0; s < sendToStudent.length; s++) { //start loop through students array to send
    var student = sendToStudents[s].replace(/\s+/g, '');
    for (r=1; r < sheet2.getLastRow(); r++) { //start loop across entire roster sheet
      var studentInRoster = allRosterValues[r][2].replace(/\s+/g, '');
      if (String(sendToStudents[s]) == String(allRosterValues[r][2])) { //look for student email in array to match roster list
        Logger.log("SEND EMAIL HERE");
        break;
      }
    }
 }
}
```

The problem is, this if statement always catches the first email match and works, but every other email after (so the second email in the form, sendToStudent[s]...) never matches.  I started directly declaring everything within the if statement, and now have declared individual var's for each step hoping that might work.  I've printed them out and can literally see how the email strings will match 100%, no white space or anything, and it just passes it by. I've checked they match type, and even removed whitespace and printed them out with a "-" before and after to check the length. It's all lowercase and I've changed the case to lowercase just to check. It even logged "not match" when I checked things using an else statement so it's actually running the if statement and not recognizing a match.  I'm totally lost!

Comment: the break statement within the if block is intended? Try removing it if it is not

Comment: Yes, I intended on using the break. Otherwise, an email is sent but the loop continues through the rest of the roster 100+ people.  I put it there so it would end that loop and immediately start checking for a match on the second student's email address.

Comment: Is there a case issue on the compare?  Maybe convert to lowercase then compare?

Comment: no, it's all lowercase.  I'll add that the description...

Comment: What about if (String(student) == String(studentInRoster)). You are stripping into variables but not using them.

Comment: Thanks @JAZ That totally worked!  I've tried changing so many things (stripping into variables being the most recent) I just never actually changed the loop.  sheesh.

Answer (score 0):

Stripping to variables, as mentioned by JAZ, did the trick.